# Stop sliding back of slide in slidemenu on Item Click in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have built an slidemenu using coboltforge.slidemenu library for android tablet. I dont want the slide to go back on item click and perform respective task on full screen. I want slide to stay on and the item click task will open in remaining space(on right). Space is not issue as it is for tablet.

Answer (score 0):

For the sliding menu, I recommend https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. It is widely used by popular apps like VLC for Android and Wunderlist2.

Then you should check its example of [ResponsiveUIActivity](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/ResponsiveUIActivity.java) and its related implementation. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok, I check it once if I can get something out of it. I can not change library as it is big project. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Inderjeet

Well then, at least you can reference it. Since you don't want to hide your slidemenu, you can add res/layout-large-land/your_activity and inside it add two framelayout (one for slidemenu, and other for content).
I think you don't even need to change library, you can figure it out how it works on that example.